# How to find the CWnd related to a deleted HWND

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

When my MFC application exits, it appears that I am deleting/destroying at least 1 CWnd/HWND that I should not be cleaning up - windows protests that it cannot look up the CWnd from the HWND using Cwnd::FromHandlePermanent() because the HWND has already been deleted.

Is there any way to find what the original CWnd was?

I realise that [Inspect.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will identify the entire tree of windows UI objects by their HWNDs... but it does not provide any way to dump that tree so that I could crash my application, then search through it to find the (first) guilty item. Is there a similar tool which will allow me to list CWnd objects and dump their HWNDs to a file... or is it easy enough to write one?

Comment: Each `CWnd` has a public `m_hWnd` class member. You can easily write that to a stream, dump it using [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx), or log it any other way you see fit, along with any related information such as the window text. You can traverse the tree calling [CWnd::GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex4cy2e.aspx), starting from [AfxGetMainWnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waas15s1.aspx). I'm pretty sure, you get a debug assertion, when destroying a window you shouldn't be destroying.

Comment: Yes - I have since gone down the "easy enough to write a tool" route using GetWindow(). I have now found my culprits... but not the explanation for why Windows is trying to destroy them when I was the one who created them!!

Comment: Windows giveth, and Windows taketh. The fact that your application requested the system to create a window does not give you exclusive ownership of that window. Child windows are owned by their respective parent, and owned windows (like modal dialogs) are owned by their owner window. When the system destroys a parent or owner window, it also tears down its children and owned windows. At that point you are left with a `CWnd` object that holds a stale `m_hWnd` handle, or worse, a dangling `CWnd*`. Since you identified the `CWnd` already, check if it referred to a child or owned window.

Comment: Ah - that's really helpful... and corrects a misunderstanding in the code - thanks :-)